Login section working in local but not web server
My login page in my python/flask web app is working perfectly in local, but when its on the web server it doesn't redirect after login (to the main index.html page). It simply refreshes the loading page with the username and password cleared.
FYI my usernames and passwords are stored in the working directory under user_data/user_credentials.txt (I know its a big no-no security wise but this is just me learning how to deploy a lightweight app).
Here is the route for logging in :
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        credentials_check = check_credentials(username, password)

        if credentials_check is None:
            flash('Username not recognized. Please try again or register.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        elif credentials_check:
            user = User(username)
            login_user(user)
            session.permanent = True  # Mark session as permanent
            print(f"User {username} logged in successfully")

            # Handle redirect to the intended page
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page or url_for('index'))  # Redirect to next page or index
        else:
            flash('Invalid credentials')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html')

I'm not sure if there are any other session variables within PythonAnywhere that is causing this error or something? Thanks

Add some logging to your code to see why the authentication is failing. If you print to stderr, the output will appear in your error log so you can see the path your code is taking and why it might be taking that path instead of the one you expect.
